# What is the preferred way of CI/CD with Intel SGX applications?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, intel, sgx

I want to create a CI/CD workflow for an Intel SGX based application hosted on github. The problem with that is most of the publicly available platforms, afaik, such as Travis, Circle do not have sgx enabled machines. 
Installing Jenkins on a privately owned machine is one option but I want to explore other possibilities as well.